# Security risks of gnuplot web interface

Tags: django, security, gnuplot

I need to make a kind of gnuplot web interface, that receives a list of commands or a file, saves it to disc and tells gnuplot to render it into png ("set terminal png; set output...").

What nasty or stupid things can user do with it (e.g. overloading cpu or RAM, accesing filesystem...)?
How can I avoid them? What potentially malicious lines should I remove before passing code to the gnuplot?

I'm running gnuplot via `subprocess.Popen` from django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER -- THIS LIST IS BOUND TO BE INCOMPLETE**

There are a few things that you'll want to disable (in the least).

in gnuplot, take a look at `help shell` -- Those allow the user to spawn an interactive shell (anything between `shell` and `logout` will need to be discarded).  Also, you'll want to remove any lines starting with `!` or `system` (and any line continuations) as those invoke shell commands.  Next on my list of potentially hazardous things to do is using backtic substitution.

```
#homeless1.gp
mysring="`rm -rf ~`"
```

will clear out your home directory.  Of course, I make no claims that if you do all these things, your script will be completely safe.  If you're only allowing the user to upload one file to run, you might as well disable `load` and `call` as well since then you don't have to worry about the user somehow uploading another malicious script and loading it from the first.

Another thought -- gnuplot allows programs to be called using pipes --  e.g.

```
plot "<awk -F, '{print $0}' mydata.txt" #runs system command awk
```

You'll need to pretty much disable any string which starts with whitespace followed by `<` or a `|` -- possibly with escape sequences in there as well since gnuplot might just silently throw those away if they're not escaping anything.

```
#homeless2.gp
MYSTRING="<rm -rf ~"
plot MYSTRING  #removes $HOME -- And doesn't even give you a plot :-(
```

and another ...

```
#homeless3.gp
set output "| rm -rf ~"
```

You could also get the script stuck in an infinite loop quite easily using `reread` -- That script is just one line long:

```
#inifite_loop.gp
reread   #Suckers!!!
```

This is one you'll probably want to disable even if you construct a chroot jail to run your scripts under (something that I know nothing about, I only learned the term while googling how to run a script safely under unix...) -- Although I suppose using the above methods, a user could still peg your one core of your CPU by constructing an infinite loop in a different programming language and executing that from gnuplot -- Same thing goes for memory I guess...

```
#infinite_mem.gp
!python -c "a=[]; while True: a.append('Suckers!!! '*10000000))" #You'll probably hit swap pretty fast with this...
```

The more I think about it, in order to do this safely, you pretty much are going to have to re-write the gnuplot parser from scratch and check everything, (or sandbox and monitor -- setting careful limits on consumed resources).

(sorry, I'm sure this isn't what you want to hear).

It seems (to me) like your best bet is to create your own mini-language which accepts only a small (but useful) subset of gnuplot commands and constructs the gnuplot script from that set of commands ...

**PROGRESS EDIT**

After playing around a bit, you can disable piping in gnuplot --

```
./configure --program-suffix=safer
```

Now, you need to edit `config.h` that was generated by configure...
comment out the lines:

```
#define HAVE_PCLOSE 1
```

and

```
#define HAVE_POPEN 1
```

and

```
#define PIPES 1
```

(e.g. `/*#define HAVE_PCLOSE 1*/` if you're not familiar with C comments).

then `make; [sudo] make install` -- with the suffix the way I've set it up, your "safer" version of gnuplot can be invoked as `gnuplotsafer`.

This disables the insecurities that arise from pipes (problems with strings that have `|`, `<`, and even backtics are now safe). **shell**, **system** and **!** are still not safe, you
ll have to disable those by parsing the script still -- but that is ALOT easier than trying to make sure the user doesn't set up malicious pipes.

I would also suggest that you check to make sure you can't do anything with the pipes/backtics, etc before you put the system online, and I would still try to sandbox the entire thing as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Everything mgilson says above is very important to understand - this can be very risky. But it should be *possible* to do safely with careful sandboxing and monitoring of resource usage.

Take a look at http://www.plotshare.com/. They've been around for a while, so they must have found a way to do this safely. Maybe you could talk to them.

Comment: surprisingly, I didn't know about plotshare.  Many (not all) of the above insecurities result from gnuplot's ability to use pipes on systems which have a `popen` function.  I'm wondering if it would be possible to build a gnuplot executable which you could fool into thinking that `popen` isn't available (maybe by modifying a line in `config.h`) -- I'm not a gnuplot dev, but it seems like something like this *should* be possible ... Maybe I'll give it a shot (just for fun) when I try to build gnuplot 4.6 ... (+1 for the link)

Comment: Well, it turns out that you **CAN** disable the pipes, and it isn't too hard either (just comment out 3 lines in `config.h` -- see above).  I suppose you could put that in the next revision of your book ;).

Comment: That's useful to know. If there is a next revision, I'll point this out (my book actually has a section describing plotshare).

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [www.plotshare.com](http://www.plotshare.com) and I just came across this entry today.

I want to send my thanks to mgilson for making the page safer with his remarks. To be honest, the pipe security issue wasn't on my radar because I tend to preprocess my data before plotting and therefore rarely used pipes.

I run the page as a free time project and constantly try to improve it. For now I hope that most of the security holes are stuffed.

@Lee Phillips: Thanks for including the plotshare in your book. Right now I am in the progress of adding some nice features (improved help system, html canvas, etc...) to make the online plotting experience truly superior to just using gnuplot from shell.

When I am confident about the quality of the page, I will put some more effort into the visibility on google. Just let me know if you don't like something about the page or miss a particular feature.